# Pandas dataframe replace does not replace values

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a code that takes value in cell, changes it and the it should replace value in that cell with new value. I have `.replace` function fit dummy dataframe, and it works, but for my example it does not work.
Old value and new value are very long strings. I have tried with `inplace=True` and without it.

My goal is to change `ServiceDirection` value.

You can download the data from here:

https://www.sendspace.com/file/7soufd

old value looks like this:
`...ype=1|ServiceDirection=2|CmtsMdIfIn...`

new value looks like this:
`ype=1|ServiceDirection=DS|CmtsMdIfIn`

This is the code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def third_task():

    new_data = data

    for column in data:

        for row in data[column]:

            if 'ServiceDirection=1' in str(row):

                new_row = str(row).replace('ServiceDirection=1', 'ServiceDirection=DS')
                new_data = data.replace(str(row), new_row)

            elif 'ServiceDirection=2' in str(row):

                new_row = str(row).replace('ServiceDirection=2', 'ServiceDirection=US')
                new_data = data.replace(str(row), new_row)


    export_csv = new_data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\export_dataframe1.csv', index = None, header=False)

    return new_data

print(third_task())
```

I have also tried to do this:

`df.replace(row, result)`

Instead of this:
`data[column] = data[column].replace(str(row), str(result), inplace=True)`

But still does not work, it always returns dataframe with old values

Comment: Can you give a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @Terry I updated the question, you have the database in there

Comment: I see problem when I read to `for row in data['column']`

Comment: Whats the problem? @QuangHoang

Comment: your .csv is so messy, What are you trying to do with this data?

Comment: I know my CSV is messy, but my task is not to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you are trying to structure your data. If so, I did it this way.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep = '|', header = None)
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :].apply(lambda x: x.split('=')[0])
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('=').str.get(1))
df.head()

    ServiceSlaDelayPkts ServiceTimeCreated  CmtsMdIfName    ServiceSlaDropPkts  ServiceGateId   ServiceClassName    CmtsSysUpTime   ServicePktsPassed   ServiceIdentifier   ServiceDsMulticast  ... ServiceTimeActive   CmMacAddr   ServiceOctetsPassed ServiceAppId    CmtsHostName    RecCreationTime RecType ServiceDirection    CmtsMdIfIndex   ,,,
0   0   4199286300  Cable1/0/0  0   0   USXnet  4294746100  7710    13  0   ... 954374  aaaa.bbbb.cccc  1033134 7   ibis-instruments-1.com  1555675968867   1   2   1001    NaN
1   0   4199286300  Cable0/0/0  0   0   DSXnet  4294746100  287 14  0   ... 954374  aaaa.bbbb.cccc  96868   7   ibis-instruments-1.com  1555675968867   1   1   1001    NaN
2   0   4199290300  Cable1/0/0  0   0   USXnet  4294746100  9527731 15  0   ... 954284  dddd.bbbb.cccc  1471545334  7   ibis-instruments-1.com  1555675968867   1   2   1001    NaN
3   0   4199290300  Cable0/0/0  0   0   DSXnet  4294746100  128871002   16  0   ... 2968    dddd.bbbb.cccc  188935852314    7   ibis-instruments-1.com  1555675968867   1   1   1001    NaN
4   0   4260449700  Cable0/0/0  0   0   USXnet  4294746100  452297  17  0   ... 342739  dddd.bbbb.mmmm  77459364    7   ibis-instruments-2.com  1555675968868   1   2   1001    NaN
```

---

### Edit: Add dots and upper case on CmMacAddr column

```
df['CmMacAddr'] = df['CmMacAddr'].str.replace('.', '').str.upper()

df['CmMacAddr'] = df['CmMacAddr'].apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(x), 2)))
```

---

### Explanation

The first line of code read the .csv separating the columns  by '|' (the default is comma(,)).
The second line i rename the columns names, because your csv dont have `header`, i selected only one row (`df.iloc[0, :]`) and then I cover all values(`apply`) spliting by '=' and taking the values from index 0.
The last line of code is very similar to the second, but i take se second value from each split and replace all rows with this new value.
If you execute row by row my code and adding `df.head()` between them you will see the evolution :)

Comment: `CmMacAddr` column is like this `dddd.bbbb.mmmm`, and needs to be like this  `DD.DD.BB.BB.MM.MM`

Can you please update your answer and explain me this

`df.columns = df.iloc[0, :].apply(lambda x: x.split('=')[0])
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('=').str.get(1))`

Your answer is amazing, but I do not know why did you do this?

Comment: Your answer is amazing, but my data needs to have the same structure like on the start.

Comment: As I said, your answer is amazing , and Ill put it as a correct, but If you can please help me without changing the data structure, because thats how I need to solve this. Thanks

Comment: I do not know how to do it that way mate. I hope someone shows up with the correct answer